# How does one prove that center of mass does not accelerate on the two masses on a spring system? (at resonance condition)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, spring

This is my attempts so far,

$$\vec{r} = \frac{ \vec r_1 m_1 + \vec r_2 m_2}{m_1+m_2}$$

$$\dot{\vec{r}} = \frac{ \dot{\vec r_1} m_1 + \dot{\vec r_2} m_2}{m_1+m_2}$$

$${\ddot{\vec{r}}} = \frac{ {\ddot{\vec r_1} }m_1 + {\ddot{\vec r_2}} m_2}{m_1+m_2}$$

Now I don't get how to prove that the second time derivative of position is in fact equal to 0 ( condition for non-accelerating center of mass)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106781/discussion-between-ddd4c4u-and-ggcg).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are having problem in putting force equation correctly, but I would provide the answer for a general case i.e you would pull both mass oppositely , however result would be same if you push both masses

first of all, your force equation is incorrect, 
 if you push both mass inside or outside, then the spring would get compressed or extended
 to apply force equation to individual masses you need to consider total expansion or compression length the spring had to undergo

if you pull spring by both ends having different masses attached, let the elongation over the whole spring be $x$
 then force on any mass such as $m_1$ 
would be

$k\,x$ $=$ $m_1\,a_1$

since the spring would try to compress from opposite direction as well so force on another mass $m_2$ would have same value but with its direction changed

$-k\,x$ $=$ $-m_2\,a_2$

put it in center of mass equation you would get acceleration of whole system $0$ (Note : the acceleration $a_2$ should be opposite of $a_1$, so don't forget negative sign)

your equation was faulty because you were considering different elongation or compression of spring for both masses , but you need to consider the whole compression or expansion of spring

Comment: I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around how compression of one mass is extension of the other half of the spring

Comment: You are not compressing masses you are compressing the spring.  The compression of the spring is directly related to the coordinates of the masses.  Please see my comments in chat and read the other post that was mentioned in the comments.  This has the spring length listed as $|x_1 - x_2|$

Comment: @DDD4C4U you mentioned in the comments of question, that you are deriving it for general case, you said  *The most general case, that is if I push the two masses inside or if I pull both outside*

Comment: Oh yeah my bad I got what you meant now